# How can I pass a param as a key?

Tags: karate

I have the following case and need to use firstKeyStr as a key, my code now is seeing "#firstKeyStr" as the key not the one stored in it

**Code**

```
Given path '/api/v1/sites'

When method get

Then status 200
    
And match response.success == true
    
And match response.data == "#object"
    
* def keys = karate.keysOf(response.data)
    
* def firstKeyStr = keys[0]

And match response.data."#firstKeyStr" == "#object"
```

**Json Response Body**

```
{

"success": true,

    "data": {

        "5ef34d0ca5a3c56ae14d2a23": {

            "devices": [

                "5f03192010a47f3e5b714193"

            ],

            "groups": [   
       
                "5f0d9f30ef89e22778a2d230"

            ],

            "users": [],

            "triggers": [],

            "alerts": [

                "5f0d92b967bac60b84d3989b"

            ],

            "name": "test",

            "country": "US",
            ]
        }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to pass this dynamic key (5ef34d0ca5a3c56ae14d2a23) in this line (And match response.data."#firstKeyStr" == "#object")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Peter said, your JSON is not well formed and the order of keys is not guaranteed (unless you have just a single key). The following code should get you going.

**Sample Code:**

```
Feature: firstKey

Scenario: firstKey
    * def resp = 
    """
    {

    "success": true,
        "data": {
            "5ef34d0ca5a3c56ae14d2a23": {
                "devices": [
                    "5f03192010a47f3e5b714193"
                ],
                "groups": [   
           
                    "5f0d9f30ef89e22778a2d230"
                ],
                "users": [],
                "triggers": [],
                "alerts": [
                    "5f0d92b967bac60b84d3989b"
                ],
                "name": "test",
                "country": "US"
                }
            }
    }
    """
        
    And match resp.data == "#object"
    * def keys = karate.keysOf(resp.data)
    * def firstKeyStr = keys[0]
    * print firstKeyStr
    * print (resp.data[firstKeyStr])

    And match (resp.data[firstKeyStr]) == "#object"
```

Comment: it's part of the json returned by the API (Not the full one), I added it to explain that the key here is dynamic, I can not def the resp since I can not guess the keys

Comment: You need not def the response. This was just a sample code to validate the first key's value is a valid JSON object which was your objective in your question. You will need to tweak it for your actual response.

Comment: Oh I see now, thank you Neodawn it worked, I'm new to Karate, using it for just couple of weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Use round brackets so that JS is used instead of JsonPath:

```
* def response = { data: { a: 1, b: 2 } }
* def keys = karate.keysOf(response.data)
* def first = keys[0]
* match (response.data[first]) == 1
```

Comment: didn't work. In my case firstKeyStr is a dynamic customer id something like 5ef34d0ca5a3c56ae14d2a23 returned with the response inside the data object

Comment: @Orjuwan I'm giving up. your example is badly incomplete and I tried to guess. so follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @PeterSmith I added more details to my question hope it is clear now, thank you

Comment: @Orjuwan no I tried, your json is not well-formed. I also feel this is a bad way of testing, the order of keys in json is not guaranteed. please read the docs on `match each`. I request other karate users here to help you, I'm out